# $scope.$watch doesn't trigger on every change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularJS 1.4.8, yesterday i noticed that the $scope.$watch doesn't trigger on every change which caused bug in my application.

is there a way to force it to work on every change immediately ?
like in this code, in every change on message i want the function in watch to trigger:

```
(function(){

  angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myAppController', myAppController)

  function myAppController($scope){
    console.log('controller loading !');
    $scope.message = 'message1';

    $scope.$watch('message', function(newMessage){
      console.log('newMessage', newMessage)
    });

    function changeMessage(){
      $scope.message='hi';
      $scope.message='hi12';
    }

    changeMessage(); 
  }

})();
```

the console will print:

```
controller loading !
newMessage hi22
```

plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/SA1AcIVwr04uIUQFixAO?p=preview

edit:
I would really like to know if there are any other ways than wrapping the change with timeout and using scope apply, in my original code iv'e multiple places where i change the scope property and i would like to avoid using this every change.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521627/3551786)

Comment: @Durga iv'e multiple place where i change my object in my original code,is there any other way than wrap everything in timeout with scope apply?

Comment: I think is because the `$watch` function only activates after angular has finished compiling. So when ever you change the `$scope`, after the controller is initialized, the `$watch` will trigger.

Comment: you need that only for `message` change in `scope` to trigger a listener?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is $watch not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441460/why-is-watch-not-firing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

update your changeMessage function so that it uses $scope.$apply function which will ensure that your changes are reflected and angular is aware of your changes to the variable.

```
changeMessage() {
   setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
          $scope.message = "Timeout called!";
        });
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: iv'e multiple place where i change my object in my original code,is there any other way than wrap everything in timeout with scope apply?

Comment: warping your code in scope apply is best practice as it ensure that the your changes are updated, It is not at all recommended to skip this.
As said by you, in your code were your are having multiple instances were your object is being modified, it becomes an ideal way for you to this, i would suggest you to write a function which does this task.

you can read more about scope apply and why it is useful to use here http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: Why do you need `setTimeout` with `$apply`? You can do the same thing with `$timeout` without `$apply` or vice versa. `$apply` is running `$digest` and `$timeout` do the same thing at the end. You can read about it here: https://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-apply-timeout-digest-evalasync/

Comment: @Kindzoku we need setTimeout with apply because if we do not use the setTimeout then chances are high that the current digest cycle is in progress and we might be changing our variable while it is in progress which will eventually lead to error. Using setTimeout ensure that our chnages are always made after the current digest cycle is complete.

Comment: 2 seconds delay won't guarantee that $digest not in progress. You can use `$$phase` for this. But `$$` is not recommended. I just don't get it, how 2 seconds delay will solve this. setTimeout not wrapped by angular. Angular knows nothing about setTimeout and $digest loop is not connected to it by any means.

Comment: @Kindzoku, you are right 2 sec delay wont guaranty that $digest is in progress, and it that nothing to do with 2 sec it can even be 100 ms also, that fact that this works gracefully is that angular will only process the code wrap in setTimeout after the completion of current $digest cycle

Comment: `setTimeout` is `async`. It can guarantee nothing and it's not connected to `$digest` by any means. `setTimeout` with `$apply` inside guarantee only the fact that `$apply` will shoot after time mentioned in `setTimeout`. It is not related to `$digest`. And `$timeout` do the same thing after the hood.

Comment: This is really not a good way to apply changes to the `$scope`. Much better would be to use the build in `$timeout` function.

Comment: "warping your code in scope apply is best practice" this is so wrong. When do you use $apply? From outside the scope/digest loop...Were are we? In the scope/digest loop...

Answer (score 11):

This happens because the watch will only be triggered if the value is changed "between" digest loops.

Your function is changing the message value on the scope in the same function. This will be executed in the same digest loop.
When angular moves on to the next loop it will only see the last changed value which in your case will be `hi22`.

[Here's](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/) a great article which makes this behaviour clear

Answer (score 4):

If you change  value into the same digest cycle the watcher is not triggered and last value is taken. When we run `$timeout`, we change `$scope.message` value in next digest cycle and watcher catches it as expected.

Take look on simple test:

```
 $scope.$watch(function(){
  console.log('trigger');
  return $scope.message;
},
  function(newMessage){
  console.log('newMessage', newMessage)
});

function changeMessage(){
  $scope.message='hi';

  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.message='hi12';
  });      
}
```

*Output:*

```
controller loading !
 trigger
 newMessage hi
 trigger
 trigger
 newMessage hi12
 trigger
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to wrap changeMessage in setTimeout and $apply at the same time. If you need to skip some time before execution, just use:

```
function changeMessage(){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.message = 'message';
    }/* or add time here, doesn't matter */);
}
```

Or just:

```
function changeMessage(){
    $scope.message = 'message';
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Both methods calls `$rootScope.$digest` in the end. Here is more information: https://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-apply-timeout-digest-evalasync/

Answer (score 2):

`$watch()` only triggers between every `$digest()`.

[Detailed explaination about the `$apply()` and `$digest()`](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)

In your case you keep updating the `$scope.message` in the current `$digest()` cycle.

You could change that by applying each new value to the  `$scope` using `$apply()`. Like @Ajinkya wrote.
The only problem, with setting 2000ms as timeout, doesn't allways ensure it executes after the `$digest()`. On top of that, Angular has a build in  timeout function. See below.

```js
(function(){
  
  angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myAppController', myAppController)
  
  function myAppController($scope, $timeout){
    console.log('controller loading !');
    $scope.message = 'message1';
    
    $scope.$watch('message', function(newMessage){
      console.log('newMessage', newMessage)
    });
    
    function changeMessage(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
          $scope.message='hi12';
        });
    }, 2000);
      
    }
    
    changeMessage(); 
  }
  
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppController"></div>
```

---

### Solution

The best way would be to call the build in `$timeout` function, without setting the time in milliseconds.

This way, angular allways ensures the `$timeout` will run after the latest `$digest()`. On top of that. You dont have to use the `$scope.$apply()`. Because the `$timeout` allready runs a `$digest()`, where `$scope.$apply()` is manually invoking a new `$diggest()` cycle.

```js
(function(){
  
  angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myAppController', myAppController)
  
  function myAppController($scope, $timeout){
    console.log('controller loading !');
    $scope.message = 'message1';
    
    $scope.$watch('message', function(newMessage){
      console.log('newMessage', newMessage)
    });
    
    function changeMessage(){
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.message='hi12';
        });
      
    }
    
    changeMessage(); 
  }
  
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppController"></div>
```